# ruby on rails rendering json in js.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

In a create method in controller I have the following code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render json: { html: render_to_string(partial: '/users/photos/card', object: @photo, as: 'photo') } }
end
```

which works perfectly. Now I would like to move this in create.js.erb to have the possibility to execute additions js. However I do not figure out how to render the json above in create.js.erb.

Any idea how to accomplish this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, what you are trying to achieve is to be able to access your JSON inside a js.erb view. In order to accomplish that, what I've done in the past is the following:

In your create.js.erb:

```
var yourJSON = JSON.parse("<%= raw(j render :partial => '/users/photos/card', object: @photo, as: 'photo') %>");
```

And in your controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js # This will render the create.js.erb
  format.json { render :partial => '/users/photos/card' } # Leave this one in case you also want to be able to respond to this format i.e: "http://localhost:3000/users/photos/card/id.json"
end
```

Hope this helps!

P.S: Let me know if you were trying to achieve something different.